# Is a BCD generic?

Tags: windows, boot, windows-8.1, bcd, recovery-disk

I have 2 computers both running Windows 8.1 (updated from the Store), and one of them won't boot. Upon booting, I get this error message:

> Your PC needs to be repaired
>
> The Boot Configuration Data file is missing some required information
>
> File: \BCD
>   Error code: 0x0000034
>
> You'll need to use the recovery tools on your installation media. If you don't have any installation media (like a disc or USB device), contact your system administrator or PC manufacturer

I don't have any installation media, and as far as I know, my PC manufacturer doesn't provide one.

My question is, can I create recovery media from my other PC (which is from a different manufacturer) and use that to repair my BCD, or does the recovery media have to be generated from the same machine?

Comment: A `Windows 8.1 Recovery Disk` is a `Windows 8.1 Recovery Disk`.

Comment: So it doesn't matter what system it was made on, it will always be the same?

Comment: The` Windows 8.1 Recovery Disk` will be the same. The boot configuration data is an entirely another story.  The tools require to regenerate the BCD will likely be on the Recovery Disk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say try it; the boot-repair-process is pretty much the same for any Windows 8/8.1 system.

If it doesn't work and you have your Windows 8 license key, you can [download a Windows 8 ISO](http://www.redmondpie.com/download-windows-8-iso-x86-x64-file-directly-from-microsoft/) direct from microsoft, and use that to fix your system:

1. Go to the [Windows 8 Upgrade Page](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-8/upgrade-product-key-only)
2. Locate the **Install Windows 8** button, and click it to run the utility
3. Enter your license key when prompted. The utility will download about 3GB of installation data
4. When prompted how you want to install, select **Install by creating media**
5. Select **ISO File** when prompted
6. Burn the iso to a DVD, and then use that to repair the bootloader

Comment: The Windows 8.0  tool used to download the ISO will only accept Upgrade license keys.  The Windows 8.1 tool will only accept 8.1 licenses, since 8.0 licenses can only be used to activate a 8.1 installation, you need an actual 8.1 license to use it.  I am not aware of any other method provided by Microsoft ( except perhaps MSDN, ect ) to get a copy of a Windows 8 ISO

Comment: Thanks, just using a repair disk from my other Windows 8 computer worked!